# Error Checking Package that Depends on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a few packages that depend on ggplot2 and have run into issues when I run `R CMD check coefplot_1.1.7.tar.gz`.

I get the error below.

```
* checking whether the package can be loaded ... ERROR
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package 'ggplot2' could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) :
  there is no package called 'ggplot2'
Execution halted

It looks like this package has a loading problem: see the messages for
details.
```

This message occurs for all of my packages that depend on ggplot2, not just this one.

It builds, installs and works just fine, but for some reason the check fails.

I had some funky stuff going on with my .libPaths argument in the Rprofile.site file in R 2.14.2 so I did a fresh install of R 2.15.0 and still have this problem.

Is this a known issue with ggplot or have I unwittingly started doing something wrong?

**EDIT** In my Rgui (through RStudio) `.libPaths()` returns

```
[1] "C:/Users/Jared/Documents/R/win-library/2.15"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.0/library"        
[3] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/library"
```

While getting to the R termnial from the cmd prompt returns

```
[1] "C:/Users/Jared/Documents/R/win-library/2.15"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.0/library"
```

And getting to the R termnial through GitBash (MINGW32) returns

```
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.0/library"
```

I'm sure that is causing some of the problem?  Maybe I need to fix this through Rprofile.site: `.libPaths("~/R/win-library/2.15")`?

Comment: One reason that this might happen is because one has packages in different folders (i.e. different libraries). `R CMD check` uses a vanilla R config, so might not be finding packages in other libraries. To fix this, you need to set up a `check.Renviron` file.

Comment: I thought about that (not exactly, but that general idea) which is why I did a clean install of R 2.15.0 and did the check there.  Incidentally, this only recently started being a problem.

Comment: If you have `.Rprofile` and other files hanging over from the previous installation, then a clean install won't make a difference. Check your `.Rprofile`, `check.Renviron`, etc.

Comment: @Andrie I put `.libPaths("C:/Users/Jared/Documents/R/win-library/2.15")` (which is where the packages are installed) in the Rprofile.site for R 2.15.0 but it still does not work.  It works for R 2.13.1, but that Rprofile.site doesn't change the library at all.  I am very confused now.

Comment: @Andrie Had luck with this: `R CMD check coefplot_1.1.7.tar.gz -l ~/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/`.  In the past I must have had better luck with the `Rprofile.site` file, but for some reason don't anymore.